# Exchange script?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to run my Exchange script, which should move all emails from one folder to another folder, but im getting this error:

> Error: The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user. Check the source and the target folders. One of them is probably invalid.

Have anyone encountered this problem before? If so, how to fix it? Both folders are there.

```
.\MoveEmails.ps1 -MailboxName email@email.com -SourceFolder Inbox -SourceType primary -TargetFolder Archive -TargetType archive -Username "email@email.com" -Password "password"
```

Comment: what's in moveemail.ps1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error

```
 .\MoveEmails.ps1 -MailboxName email@email.com-SourceFolder Hotels `
-SourceType primary -TargetFolder games -TargetT
ype primary -username "email@email.com" -password "password"
```

Have a nice day :)